# Como conseguir uma tabela para web otimizada para mostragem de cerca de 100 mil dados

Tags: php, jquery, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Estou com um serviço para fazer e preciso de uma tabela otimizada para funcionar com grande quantidade de dados, cerca de 100 mil rows no mínimo...
Na qual a pessoa vai digitando e vai filtrando os dados

Temos algumas mas não funciona com essa quantidade de dados.

Aceito ideias, direcionamentos...

Comment: Cara não é por nada não, mas, acho meio difícil encontrar uma que faça com essa quantidade de dados. Filtrar 100 mil linhas, sem falar que vai sobrecarregar o tráfego de dados, e se a Internet de quem for usar isso for ruim??

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap dataTables.

Você utiliza algum framework MVC? Se sim, é melhor ainda para configurar este plugin. Se não, recomendo o CodeIgniter para fazer isso.

Você configura a tabela para buscar os dados via Ajax. Insere o Length como 10, 25, 50, 100 etc... a quantidade que desejar. Então, quando carregar a página, ele vai buscar as informações no arquivo que está sendo informado na url. Mas, cuidado, caso você não configure corretamente, pode travar a página por causa da quantidade de informações.